# Kill with voltage

Tags: power, electromagnetism

Is it possible to get so much volt in you, that you become capable of killing another human being

Example: the game ''infamous''. In the game, you are literally living on volts.

So my question is simple: is it possible to get so much volts in you, that if I was to touch your arm, you would immedieatly die of all the volts going your body?

Comment: @JYelton: Huh?  This question makes no sense and displays a fundamental lack of understanding about things electrical.

Comment: You can't get "much volt in you".  That simply makes no sense.  Not only is the plural of "volt" "volts", but volts aren't things, so they can't be "in" anything.

Comment: @Olin I forgot my <sarcasm> tags. :)

Comment: It's interesting how comments "magically" disappear. Olin's comment is now referencing a deleted comment of mine in which I said this was the "Best Question Ever!" While the comment may not have necessarily been helpful, it was adding some humor. What's wrong with that?

Comment: It could be possible for two people, isolated from any common ground to have sufficient potential difference between them that their coming into contact would result in risk of injury/death.  The interesting question would be if there are any extreme circumstances (High altitude, low opening parachute jump *through* a thunderstorm?) where the *electrostatic* charge on the body itself could carry enough energy, or if sufficiently extreme charges would always be dissipated by something else before reaching a situation where they could kill.

Comment: Video games give people the wrong impression on how electricity works... uhhhhh

Answer (score 4):

no.

You can't "put volts in you", but you can accumulate static charge. you cannot accumulate enough of charge to kill another person by touching them, there is simply nowhere to store it on your body.

But you can store a tiny bit of very high voltage charge on you so you could zap another person a little, you can do this by stroking a cat on a dry day when wearing rubber shoes.

Comment: Can you kill at least a mosquito by zapping?

Comment: Sure, if you can get the mosquito to stand on a metal plate while you scuff your shoes on the carpet ... :-)

Comment: @DaveTweed you just gave me a great idea to keep the kids busy next summer.

Comment: I'm curious how fibrillation would "work" in a mosquito.

Comment: I think the mosquito gets squashed by the paddles before it gets zapped.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a lot of volts on the human body with no ill effects. For example, see this famous YouTube video: "[High Voltage Cable Inspection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tzga6qAaBA)".

It's current flow that injures the human body. And while you do get a jolt of current by discharging from a high voltage, the limited capacitance of the body limits the total energy available, and therefore the magnitude/duration of the current.

And it's hard to keep a human charged up anyway; it tends to leak off to the environment because of humidity, corona discharge, etc.

Comment: Suppose you can actually charge your body to a sufficient level of energy and voltage. Then, when you touch your adversary, you will create a series circuit, so the same current that flows through your foe will flow through you and you will both drop dead (I'm sure it's going to be quite a sight).

Comment: Actually, no. It's really difficult to get a static electricity dicharge to flow through the core of the body where it can cause death. The charge is distributed on the surface of the skin to begin with, and the high-frequency currents associated with a rapid discharge also tend to flow on the surface as well (called "skin effect" for good reason). The most you'll both get is a burn at the point(s) of contact, where the current is more concentrated. It isn't like getting struck by lightning, which involves many orders of magnitude more current and energy.